# Relationship between number of segments and piece-length in piece wise linearisation of circle.

Tags: geometry

I have a circle of radius $r$ governed by $p^2+q^2=r^2$. I have made total $N$ segments of $q$ from $-r$ to $r$ and $p$ is obtained from the equation $p=\sqrt{r^2-q^2}$. For complete circle total $2*N-2$ line segments will be there (without lines at $q=+r, \;-r$). As it is clear that segments have not been obtained from the angle variations, the length of segments will not be same and depends upon the value of $q$.

Now, how can I obtain a relationship between the length of these segments (chords) and the number $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall use $(x,y)$ instead of $ (p,q) $ and use differentials themselves to denote differences instead.

$$ x^2+y^2= R^2 $$

differentials

$$ \, x\,dx+ y\, dy =0  $$

Chord length $ds$

$$ ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2 \,$$

Eliminate $dy$ from above two and simplify

$$ ds= \dfrac{R\,dx}{y} = \dfrac{R\,dx}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}.  $$

Comment: For $R=65, dx=6.8421, dy=y=29.029$ the value of $ds=15.32$ while $dx^2+dy^2=29.84$ Why so?

Comment: Please check . Show how you get $29.029$. Also $y$ cannot be equal $dy$, it should be larger.

Comment: If $y_1=0$ and $y_2=29.029$ then i get $dy=y$. Also I want to ask that is this differentiation valid for large values of $dx,dy$ or need to intigrate for each section?

Comment: The conversion of differentials to differences is valid for large number of ( theoretically infinite). $0$ to $29.029$ step is too big in comprision.

Comment: It will be great if you can show me $ds$ using this formulation for an irregular polygon inscribing a circle or a source for this will be great too.

Comment: What is the  problem in computing $ds=f(x)= \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2/R^2}}, (x, -R,R,dx); dx<<R ,\, const \, dx $?

Answer (score 1):

Chord length is $$s_k=\frac{4r}{N} \sqrt{k  (N-k)};\;\text{ for }k=1,2,\ldots,N-1$$
Because points have $q_k=-r+\dfrac{2kr}{N}$

plugging this in the equation of the circle we get the chord length

$$s_k=2 \sqrt{r^2-\left(-r+\frac{2 k r}{N}\right)^2}=\frac{4 r \sqrt{k (N-k)}}{N}$$

For instance, in circle $p^2+q^2=4$ you have

$
\begin{array}{l}
 s_1=\frac{12}{5} \\
 s_2=\frac{16}{5} \\
 s_3=\frac{4 \sqrt{21}}{5} \\
 s_4=\frac{8 \sqrt{6}}{5} \\
 s_5=4 \\
 s_6=\frac{8 \sqrt{6}}{5} \\
 s_7=\frac{4 \sqrt{21}}{5} \\
 s_8=\frac{16}{5} \\
 s_9=\frac{12}{5} \\
\end{array}
$

Hope it is useful

[image]

Comment: What about the situation when we do piecewise linearization of the circle?

Comment: I tried to answer to your question. This is another question. What do you mean with "piecewise linearization"?

Comment: I have mentioned this in the question line too anyway I want to approximate the circular periphery with $N$ lines. These lines will be in between successive  $q$ & $p$  obtained as described in the question. Now I need a function of those line lengths in terms of $N$ and other constants.

Comment: you approximate circle as an irregular polygon.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, and I am looking for the relation between the number of polygon sides with polygon side length for a particular radius.